# Resources for Scrum

Tags: scrum, resources

I'm looking for resources for Scrum. Online resources would be particulary suited, but I'm ready to consider books. There is much material available, and I have to say it's hard to choose the good ones. Can you help?

I'm not only looking for tutorial, but also for documents presenting the advantages and drawbacks of the method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd recommend a lightweight book you can find online for free. It is [Scrum and XP from the Trenches](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/scrum-xp-from-the-trenches) by Henrik Kniberg. It describes how SCRUM was implemented in a company with a lot of tips and insights about the process.

Comment: Would add also some videos: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Fail-Scrum-Henrik-Kniberg

Comment: I even found a french translation, also for free. Great!

Answer (score 7):

- On Mike Cohn's site you'll find nice basic [introduction to Scrum](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/topics/scrum).
- I also recommend [Mike's articles](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/articles) on Scrum, as he has reasonable and down-to-earth approach to the method.
- [Henrik Kniberg's minibook](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/scrum-xp-from-the-trenches) pointed by OrenD in the other answer is great as well.
- Then, there's a list of [recommended readings on Scrum Alliance](http://www.scrumalliance.org/scrum_student_resources) site. Btw: skip Scrum introduction there as it is aimed at selling you one of their courses.
- If you look for more orthodox approach to the method you can check out Ken Schwaber's work: [his blog](http://kenschwaber.wordpress.com/) and [his articles](http://www.controlchaos.com/my-articles/).

Answer (score 3):

I am a fan of [All About Agile](http://www.allaboutagile.com/). The site has good articles on the basics in addition to aggregating the best articles from around the web. If you are looking for books, I recommend taking a look at Jurgen Appelo's list of [top 20 agile books](https://web.archive.org/web/20190717154429/http://noop.nl/2008/06/top-20-best-agile-development-books-ever.html).

Answer (score 2):

Scrum though prescriptive is very lightweight and needs to be augmented with technical practices.  If you could buy just one book I would recommend Mike Cohn's User Stories Applied.  In this book Mike covers Scrum in as much detail as some specific Scrum books and also provides great depth on one of the essential practices needed to be successful with Scrum.

Answer (score 2):

If you will consider **books**, the classics from Ken Schwaber: "*Agile software development with Scrum*" (ISBN 0130676349) and "*Agile Project Management with Scrum*" (ISBN 073561993X) are still good value.

More general Agile (but still with references to Scrum) are Mike Cohn's classics. The already mentioned "*User Stories Applied*" (ISBN 0321205685) and "*Agile estimating and planning*" (ISBN 0131479415).

For **online** resources I second "*[Scrum and XP from the trenches](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/scrum-xp-from-the-trenches)*". Is also liked the summary given in "*[Scrum Primer](https://scrumprimer.org/scrumprimer20_small.pdf)"* and the "*[Scrum rules Cheat Sheet](http://www.agileadvice.com/2007/10/23/referenceinformation/scrum-rules-cheat-sheet-updated-3/)*".

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure why the [official scrum guide](http://www.scrum.org/Scrum-Guides) has not been listed. The last time it was updated is Oct 11 but it is due to be updated this year.

Other links:

- [Scrum Crazy links](http://www.scrumcrazy.com/My+Preferred+Agile,+Scrum,+and+XP+Resources)
- [The Scrum Kickoff Planner - Adam Weisbart](https://weisbart.com/kickoff)
- [Essential Scrum Glossary - Innolution](http://www.innolution.com/resources/glossary)
- [Glossary of Scrum Terms - Scrum Alliance (Archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20111002191604/http://www.scrumalliance.org/articles/39-glossary-of-scrum-terms)
- [New Glossary of Scrum Terms - Victor Szalvay](http://www.volaroint.com/glossary-of-scrum-terms/)
- [SCRUM Published Patterns](https://sites.google.com/a/scrumplop.org/published-patterns/)

Comment: Link to scrum alliance Glossary is broken [See scrum.org as replacement](https://www.scrum.org/resources/scrum-glossary) or [archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20111002191604/http://www.scrumalliance.org/articles/39-glossary-of-scrum-terms)

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend "[Balancing Agility and Discipline](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321186125)" by Boehm and Turner. This book compares quite a few methodologies, each with their own characteristics on the "planning continuum".

Answer (score 0):

I usually read articles in the Agile area of DZone http://www.dzone.com/mz/agile, this place is maintained by Atlassian (JIRA maker), and it's filled with articles written by good authors like [Martin Fowler](http://java.dzone.com/users/martinfowler), [Roman Pichler](http://java.dzone.com/users/romanpichler), etc

You can look for Scrum specific articles with this tag: http://agile.dzone.com/category/tags/scrum

Comment: This posting could be improved by adding some commentary about what you find useful about this site - and whether it directly answers the question that you are answering.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the online training materials of international scrum institute. http://www.scrum-institute.org/

I also like their discussion regarding large teams and the recognition of having feature and component team in a scrum environment.