# How to write a proper Vision Document for a Scrum project

Tags: agile, scrum, pm-software

As the Scrum Framework is built interactively, I'd like to know if Scrum offers specific guidelines to define the [Vision Document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vision_document), which is usually defined based on the utmost client need.

How should the Product Owner build up the Vision Document? Is there any defined set of principles to be followed?

Comment: Hi, welcome to PMSE, the site for expert and enthusiast PM's. Consider giving more detail in your question so that it targets your unique situation. Scrum is oftentimes handled quite differently from organization to organization, and having specifics will make sure that you don't get plain, vanilla, academic answers that can be found on Google. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when the Product owner get the project what artifact he uses to develop the vision? he write a document on doc file? the problem is when talk about vision I think in vision document used in RUP.

Comment: Again, I personally think it depends on the details of your situation. If you're looking for pure academic answers you can probably find them on Google, but if you have a specific project you're referencing, you're likely to get better answers if you edit your question with more detail about your situation. :) Also, we're not a product-recommending site, but we do have some historical questions where people asked for book recommendations: http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/2114/resources-for-scrum

Comment: http://scaledagileframework.com/vision/ is a good place to start.

Answer (score 4):

Scrum has no rules about how the required documents are created. I've seen [mindmaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map), [vision boards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:VisionBoardExample.jpg) and plain word documents as a basis for the project kickoff.

The PO should consider the audience the document is for. Sometimes it is enough to sketch something on a napkin, other times you might need a full project proposal document.

You might want to read [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120601194436/https://www.scrumalliance.org/articles/115-the-product-vision) (scrumalliance.org) on product vision. It also has a few pointers to some books at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I've found conversations to be most effective.  The artifact can be subject to interpretation and later, to debate.  Building a relationship and opening a channel for conversation will get the whole process started on the right foot (and keep it there as things change).

Answer (score 0):

I think what people are getting at is there is no one way for a vision document or exercise
If you want a vision then it's not just the product owner, it's the whole team to create. Yes the PO will have alot of input but it's a team document.

Johnothan Rasmusson in the Agile Warrior uses the idea of an inception deck. I've used this on previous projects and have to say it's a good way of pulling the team together at the start and really making sure everyone is on the same page.

The article along with a blank inception deck can be found here http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2010/11/06/the-agile-inception-deck/